# Multi lambda sort for datetime

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a list of lists with which I am trying to do a multi sort lambda.
Sort first by the "on or off", then by date, in my example

Is there a better way to do this or why is my code erroring?

Below is my sample code with the lambda I am trying.

```
data = [['computer', 'on', '*N/A'], ['computer', 'off', 'Wed Jul 17 14:06:52 2019'], ['computer', 'off', 'Wed Jul 17 14:39:47 2019']['computer', 'on', '*N/A']]

data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") if (x[2] != "*N/A") else()))

print(data)
```

Expected result:

```
[['computer', 'off', 'Wed Jul 17 14:06:52 2019'], ['computer', 'off', 'Wed Jul 17 14:39:47 2019'], ['computer', 'on', '*N/A'], ['computer', 'on', '*N/A']]
```

It is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: *N/A is being filtered by the if statement and not getting passed datetime.strptime

Comment: You are replace `*N/A` with an empty tuple, not another `datetime` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `*N/A` with a valid `datetime` instance, not an empty tuple. For example,

```
def parse_date(s):
    if s != "*N/A":
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    else:
        return datetime.min  # or maybe datetime.max, depending on what result you want

data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], parse_date(x[2])))
```

Comment: Thank you, "min" returns the results I am looking for, putting the N/A first

Answer (score 0):

You should return [max datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.max) in case if date is not provided to let `list.sort()` put this items in the tail of the list.

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[2], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') if x[2] != '*N/A' else datetime.max)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue

Comment: @glwallum, choose on of answers which you find better.